# Is "real talk, me?" grammatical?

Tags: grammar, informal-language

Is "real talk, me?" grammatical? To me, it is grammatical and completely valid, and by "real talk, me?" I mean "You're expecting real talk from me (I am a clown)?". Is this sentence completely valid, or there's too many omission to be considered valid even in an informal conversation between two people who know each other well?

Comment: I would write it 'Real talk? (From) me?'

Comment: Me? The 13th Duke of Wybourne? Here? In a sixth form girl's dormitory? At three o'clock in the morning? With my reputation? What were they thinking of? - running joke in _The Fast Show_ (1990s BBC TV comedy show)

Comment: *"Hire you a horse? For ninepence? On Jewish New Year in the rain? A bare fortnight after the dreaded horse plague of Old London Town? With the blacksmith's strike in its 15th week and the Dorset Horse Fetishist's Fair tomorrow?"*, Blackadder the Third. (Another BBC TV comedy show.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I'd capitalize the first letter and replace the comma with another question mark. Thus:

> *Real talk? Me?*

Other than that, it's fine as direct speech. Now, is it completely valid **grammatically**? Well, for direct speech, as my old Yorkshire uncle used to say:

> *Completely valid grammar? In our 'ouse? Bloody luxury!*

Comment: You come 'ere with your coal mining ways - literary criticism's not good enough for you, I suppose? Or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

Is "me" a grammatical utterance?

Your utterance has very little structure.  It consists of two noun phrases. "Real talk" (an adjective-noun structure) and "me".  There is no grammatical connection between these two, so you would treat them a two independent parts.  Given your explanation, you should insert question marks, as you are asking a question (perhaps rhetorically)  "Real talk? Me?"

So, if you can accept "me" to be a complete utterance; that is, if you can accept a "naked" noun phrase to be a grammatically correct structure, you can say "Real talk? Me?"

But it isn't a sentence, it is only understandable in some conversational context. It only manages to be be grammatical by having no structure that could be called ungrammatical.